# Fraction of file modifications made by each developer

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, combinations

A project containing $f$ files is worked on by $d$ software developers; $f \approx 100d$.  A developer selects an issue to work on, and modifies one or more files (the number of files modified per issue often has the form of a power law).  It might be assumed that the total number of project issues previously worked on, $n$, is: $2f \lt n$.

There are two preferential selection processes at work:

- a developer is more likely to modify a file they previously modified, than modify a file for the first time or create a new file,
- some files are more likely to be modified than other files, e.g., change logs.

Developer $i$'s ownership of file $j$ is defined as that developer's fraction of all modifications made to file $j$, i.e., $\frac{mod_{i}}{mod_{j}}$

Developer ownership profile has been found to be *U* shaped (see below), with some files modified by nearly every developer (i.e., ownership fraction close to zero), other files only modified by one developer (i.e., ownership fraction of one), with relatively less files modified by lots to few developers.

Developers leave the project, and new ones join.
Files are created and deleted (an exponential distribution has been seen for deletion).
Developer and file half-life are similar.

**Q:** What are the characteristics of developer file ownership, and how might it evolve over time (the two ranges 0.0 to 0.3 and 0.8 to 1.0 cover most of the commits)?

There has been lots of work around rich-get-richer models, and stochastic models of vocabulary growth, but I have not found anything applicable to individual contributions.  The preferential selection/attachment models cover global characteristics, and again I have not seen any looking an individual contributions.  References welcome.

The plot below shows developer file ownership, over all developers working on 40 separate projects, at the time when each of 101,920 commits were made.  Data binned in 0.01 wide increments of ownership.

[image: ownership-file]